# Fan in my furnace will not turn on in the manual position

Tags: furnace, fans

When I turn my thermostat to the off position and my fan from auto to on the fan does not turn on. I have a Goodman electric furnace. Is this normal? The fan will run if I call for heat or cooling but not when I have system off. I was told the fan should come on when I switch from auto to run even if I am not calling for heat or cooling?

Comment: No, it's not normal. Yes, it should come on. Did you have a more specific question? If so, please revise to provide all relevant information about your system, thermostat, and wiring.

Comment: @isherwood An old system with a new thermostat is a prime example of where it would be normal. Even homes built in the 70’s routinely only had 2 wire systems that owners added programmable thermostats to save energy and every one of these I have purchased or installed has had a fan switch or program location.

Comment: Fair enough. Then we need more information from the OP.

Comment: What model is your furnace, and how many wires do you have running from your furnace to your thermostat?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many wires your thermostat has.
If you only have 2 or 3 wires it is 100% normal for there to be No connection to turn on the fan.
If you have more then it would be common to have a fan connected to the thermostat.
It also depends on the model of Goodman some are only 2 wire units.
A bypass switch can be added at the furnace location quite easily I have done this many times.

Comment: If G on the thermostat isn't connected to G on the board, then yes it is normal for it to not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a thermostat that if I turn it off, nothing works, I've just shut off the power to it and the system's down.  Moving the switch to either heat or cool, lets me run the fan in auto or run. I've had a number of them like that. It probably depends on the actual thermostat. I've installed a number of them and they have worked the same way....  off is off.